# Is there a library which allows for converting 4D implicit surfaces to simplexes?

Tags: visualization

I have a 4D surface in the form of the spin quadric. I would like to display this surface onto the screen. One of the method which I would like to use to present surface onto the screen is projection. I would like to perform 4D->3D and then 3D->2D projections.

To be able to perform a projection I need to have a set of simplexes which belongs to the surface. Unfortunately, I have only implicit form of the surface and I can't find any library which allows me to convert 4D implicit surface to simplexes.

Do you know any kind of library which allows for `converting` 4D implicit surface to simplexes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how to do this, but I checked the code of the [hypertorus screensaver](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/) and there, the programmer suggested as a reference [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Beyond-Third-Dimension-Dimensions-Scientific/dp/0716760150). I also found [this lecture notes](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~hwshen/888_su02/hanson_note.pdf).